# A program that takes user input, stores it into a list, then displays data about the list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to solve the following problem:
Write a program that allows a user to keep inputting numbers until 0 is entered. The program should store the numbers in a list, then display the following data:
The list of numbers in ascending order
The lowest number on the list
The highest number in the list
The total of the numbers in the list
The average of numbers in the list

Here's what I have so far:

```
count = 0
list = []
total = 0
average = 0
index = 0


while True:
    userInput = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    if userInput == 0:
        break
    for i in range(userInput):
        list.append(i)


list.sort()
print(list)
min_value = min(list)
max_value = max(list)
print("the min value is", min_value)
print("the max value is", max_value)

while index < len(list):
    list[index] = int(list[index])
    index += 1
for j in list:
    total += j

print("the total is", total)
average = total/len(list)
print("the average is", average)
```

The program creates a weird list, that doesn't look anything like the user input. How can I solve this issue? It would be easier if I knew the length of the list, then I could use the range function and write to the list that way, but the length of the list is up to the user :/

Comment: Your user input block almost definitely doesn't do what you probably think it does. The `input()` function returns a string, but then you cast it to an integer, but then almost immediately cast it back to string and iterate over it...?

Comment: Do you intend for the user to input all the data at once, or one number at a time?

Comment: Note also that using `list` as a variable name is bad practice, as `list` is the name of a built-in function in Python which you are overwriting.

Comment: I intend for the user to keep inputting data until 0 is entered. Once 0 is entered, the program should display the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
user_data = [] # Dont name variables that can clash with Python keywords

while True:
    userInput = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    if userInput == 0:
        break
    else:
        user_data.append(userInput) # append the value if it is not 0

print("The list in ascending order is:", sorted(user_data)) # Ascending order of list
print("the max value is", max(user_data)) # max value of list
print("the min value is", min(user_data)) # min value of list
print("the total is", sum(user_data)) # total of list
print("The average is", sum(user_data)/len(user_data)) # average of list
```

### What you were doing wrong?

1. Naming a list to a Python keyword is not a good habit. `list` is a keyword in Python.
2. **Biggest mistake**:`for i in str(userInput):` Appending `string` of the number instead of `int`. How will you get the max, min, or total with a string?
3. You don't need to create one more loop for appending. You can use the same `while loop`.
4. Calculating `total` on your own through a loop is not a bad thing. Instead, I would say a good way to learn things. But I just wanted to tell you that you can use `sum()` to get the total of a list.
5. `list.sort()` will sort the list and `print(list.sort())` would lead to `None` because it just sorts the list and doesn't return anything. To print sorted list use `sorted(listname)`

Sample Output:

```
Enter a number:12
Enter a number:2
Enter a number:0
The list in ascending order is: [2, 12]
the max value is 12
the min value is 2
the total is 14
The average is 7.0
```

I hope you understand and work on your mistakes.

Comment: I notice my mistakes, using a for loop to write to the list was a huge issue too. I am going to improve the naming problem as well. I'm a cs freshman, so everything helps!